# .NET Core 3 - Load static files on Docker enviroment

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core-3.1

I got some stupid question, but honestly I rly desperate right now.

In my .NET Core3 app, Im loading HTML template to variable with helps of absoluth path

```
var pathToFile = _env.ContentRootPath
                 + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
                 + "Templates.html"

var builder = new BodyBuilder();
using (StreamReader SourceReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
   builder.HtmlBody = SourceReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

In my testing localhost environment it works fine, bcs its accessing the file on my disk.
But the problem here is, I cant reach this file if I run my app on Linux Docker environment.

**How to properly load HTML files to variable on Docker Env with .NET Core3 ?**

Thanks for your hints

Comment: What is the error message on docker? Since it's working whey you debug it I'am assuming "Copy to output" is set to true on the file in question, is that right?

Comment: check if you copy the file in the dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks guys for your hints, Im rly embarrassed now, it was the "Copy to output" was set to False instead of True...
Now it works fine.